# Растянуть чужое окно в linux

Tags: linux

Нужны аналоги `SetWindowLong` или `SetWindowPos`, `SetWindowSize`.

В общем, нужно как-то растянуть окно gui приложения, запущенное в ubuntu. Какие способы существуют? У приложения нету `sizebox`'a по умолчанию и менять размер нельзя.

Comment: композитным менеджером отзумить)

Comment: Интересно... нужно попробовать. благодарю за совет.

Answer (score 0):

1. менять размер нельзя.
2. нужно как-то растянуть окно

Если нельзя, но очень хочется, то - можно. Это вы готовите локализацию продукта для России ? :-)

Ну а если серьёзно, то раз Вы запускаете программу под Ubuntu, то (скорее всего) она написана с использованием GTK+. Там применяются менеджеры размещения, которые устанавливают все размеры всех виджетов автоматически. Правда, существует функция `gtk_drawing_area_set_size()`. Но я ей никогда не пользовался.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Программа запускается из под Mono. Написана на unity3d.

Comment: @thez **Программа запускается из под Mono** -  извините, но здесь я Вам не советчик... :-(